# How to remove hour from links like this: "2022-06-28T00:00:00+03:00&end=2022-06-30T23:59:59+03:00"

Tags: javascript, laravel

i have a problem in laravel with links in a fullcalednar script. I need the links to be only with date: 2022-06-28 not with T00:00:00+03:00. i do this but not work any ideea?

```
 // timeZoneOffset is in minutes
function buildIsoString(marker, timeZoneOffset, stripZeroTime) {
    if (stripZeroTime === void 0) { stripZeroTime = false; }
    var s = marker.toISOString();
    s = s.replace('.000', '');
    if (stripZeroTime) {
        s = s.replace('T00:00:00Z', '');
    }
    if (s.length > 10) { // time part wasn't stripped, can add timezone info
        if (timeZoneOffset == null) {
            s = s.replace('Z', '');
        }
        else if (timeZoneOffset !== 0) {
            s = s.replace('Z', formatTimeZoneOffset(timeZoneOffset, true));
        }
        // otherwise, its UTC-0 and we want to keep the Z
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the problem. So, please bear with me.

If you want to strip the hours, minutes, seconds and miliseconds from an ISO string (from `Date.toISOString()`) you can simply do the following:

- Option 1: `isoString = isoString.slice(0, 10);`
- Option 2: `isoString = isoString.replace(/T.*$/, "");`

I'm not sure this answers your question. I would need to know more about how and where the `buildIsoString` function is being called and what the `formatTimeZoneOffset` does.

I hope this helps.